# How do find where Grails/Groovy installed on a Mac?

Tags: macos, grails, groovy

I need to know the directory path on my Mac OS where Grails and/or Groovy has been installed (not sure if these will be the same)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems `where` (bash) or `which` (ZSH) is the command you need:

```
 ~/ where groovy
/Users/opal/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/bin/groovy
 ~/ where grails
/Users/opal/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/bin/grails

 ~/ which groovy
/Users/opal/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/bin/groovy
 ~/ which grails
/Users/opal/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/bin/grails
```

BTW: Try using [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/). Highly recommended!

Comment: `OS X` doesn't use `where`, it uses `which`... unless the where command is specific to grails/groovy?

Comment: @l'L'l, no it's not. `where` is shell built-in. Updated the answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity which shell exactly? I've never come across it anywhere.

Comment: Do I just run "where" from the terminal? When I do I get the below ip-192-177-1-15:SQL jehan$ ~/ where groovy
-bash: /Users/jehan/: is a directory

Comment: @AbuMariam, `where` is ZSH built-in, try `which`.